# SQL Server 2014 Triggers and Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, trigger, merge-replication

I am trying to have a trigger fire when the Merge agent\user insert\delete\update data.
The trigger inserts data into a log table.
I don't want to use NFR (Not For Replication) because I need that the trigger will fire when merge agent inserts data.

At first, I thought it was the problem with the replication but when I change the triggers into NFR everything was working fine.
(which is not good because I need them to fire when the merge agent inserts data as well).

Then I thought it was a problem with the triggers but when I insert\update\delete data using t-sql the triggers are working fine.

The problem is that the data is not synchronized as it should be in merge replication. When I update a column, I can't see it on the other database unless I'm changing the trigger into Not For Replication or disabling them.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does NFT mean? I have read and re-read your post but I still don't get a clear picture of what happens, etc. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think NFR = Not For Replication :)

Comment: @TiborKaraszi I don't think the problem was described anywhere in the post. It's not just you.

Comment: NFR = Not For Replication :)

Comment: The problem is that the data is not synchronized as it should be in merge replication.
when I update a column i can't see it on the other database unless i'm changing the trigger into Not For Replication or disabling them.

Comment: The text initially had NFT, hence my question that that means. Probably a typo which was subsequently (silently) edited to NFR... :-) DnL: Perhaps there is some issue with firing orders for the triggers? I my memory serves me, the triggers created by merge replication need to be the last one, so if your happes to be fining after the merge trigger, then that trigger didn't know what your subsequent trigger did. Just speculation, but ... plausible, or something along those lines. Check using sp_settriggerorder.